# In report how to pull additional fields from master-detail relationship

Tags: reporting, master-detail, custom-report-type, joined-reports

I have an object Y with field X which is a lookup field of the same object(Y). I want to create a report that pulls many fields from my object (Y)(including field X and master-detail relational fields) and also pulls additional fields from the object of master-detail lives in. Can it be done?

```
Object==>Y
Field==>X==>lookup-Object==>Y
Object==>A(is child)==>master-detail==>Object Y(is master)==>Report Base on On object Y want to show fields of object A
```

**Can it be done?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with an auto-generated report type. However, you can do this with a [Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_defining_report_types.htm&type=5). Just create a Custom Report Type, then Edit the Layout, then use the option on the right-hand side field selector to *Add fields related via lookup*.

Comment: thanks for your reply!  custom report type lookup field is it possible to get child object (master-detail)fields?

Comment: @ShamimSiddique Yes, you can add the children using the Relationships option.

Comment: If I am not wrong, in a report 'related via lookup' is used to connect details to parent not a parent to child. I need child object information in a parent.